# How do I dynamically show a mobile menu with Tailwind and Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a responsive menu with Tailwind CSS and Vue.js. Currently I have this template:

```
<template>
<nav class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-pink-100 p-6">
    <div class="flex items-center flex-shrink-0  mr-6">
        <span class="font-semibold text-xl tracking-tight">Pixie</span>
    </div>
    <div class="block md:hidden" >
        <button @click='clickMenu' class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded" >
        <svg class="fill-current h-3 w-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Menu</title><path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z"/></svg>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="w-full flex-grow md:flex md:items-center md:w-auto" v-if="menuVisible">
        <div class="text-sm md:flex-grow">
        <a href="#responsive-header" class="block mt-4 md:inline-block md:mt-0 hover:text-white mr-4">
            Features
        </a>
        <a href="#responsive-header" class="block mt-4 md:inline-block md:mt-0  hover:text-white mr-4">
            Pricing
        </a>
        <a href="#responsive-header" class="block mt-4 md:inline-block md:mt-0  hover:text-white">
            Blog
        </a>
        </div>
        <div>
        <a href="#" class="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded  text-white bg-blue-500 hover:border-transparent mt-4 md:mt-0">Sign Up</a>
        <a href="#" class="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded  hover:border-transparent mt-4m d:mt-0">Log In</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</template>
```

With this Javascript:

```
<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            menuVisible: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        clickMenu: function() {
            this.menuVisible = !this.menuVisible
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

All I want to do is initially hide the mobile menu when the breakpoint reaches 'sm' on Tailwind. This would mean the user would have to click the menu button to see the menu, which I think is the expected behavior on mobile devices.

I don't want to build 2 separate menus which get shown on different breakpoints as I want to avoid duplicating code. Is there a way to access the current breakpoint for Tailwind in Vue.js? This would mean I could set the menuVisible to a computed property which only allows it to be visible if the breakpoint is desktop or tablet, or if the user has clicked the menu.

Or is there another better way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

you can write a plugin for it in you app and import it, im using nuxt and this worked for me

```html
export default (context, inject) => {
  const burger = () => {
    const menu = document.querySelector("#menu");

    if (menu.classList.contains("hidden")) {
      menu.classList.remove("hidden");
    } else {
      menu.classList.add("hidden");
    }
  };
  inject("burger", burger);
  context.$burger = burger;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

One way of achieving this could be to configure the [TailwindCSS-breakpoints](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints/) in your `tailwind.config.js` and to then reuse that file to import the breakpoint-values into your Menu-component.

Here we are setting TailwindCSS breakpoints according to [the TailwindCSS documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints/). We are actually just setting the default TailwindCSS breakpoint values, but setting them makes them accessible via the file.

```js
//tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      sm: '640px',
      md: '768px',
      lg: '1024px',
      xl: '1280px'
    }
  }
}
```

Now, in your Menu.vue, you can import the breakpoint from your TailwindCSS-config and write the necessary function, to check if the current window-size is smaller than the `md`-breakpoint. If it's not, you can simply return `true`. If it is, you can check, if the menu was toggled open.

```
// Menu.vue
<script>
const tailwindConfig = require('tailwind.config.js')

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      windowWidth: 0,
      menuOpen: false,
      mdBreakpoint: Number(tailwindConfig.theme.screens.md.replace('px', ''))
    }
  },
  computed: {
    menuVisible() {
      return this.windowWidth > mdBreakpoint ? true : this.menuOpen

    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateWindowSize() {
      this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth
    },
    clickMenu() {
      this.menuOpen = !this.menuOpen
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.updateWindowSize()
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowSize)
  },
  beforeDestroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowSize)
  }
}
</script>
```